# Derivative of $\delta (x-a)$

Tags: derivatives, dirac-delta

What is the derivative of $u(x)=\delta (x-y)H(y)$ wih respect to x and y? Thanks

Comment: It is just $\delta'(x-a)$.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I need this derivative to test my solution for a PDE. Let's say my solution is $\delta (x-y) H(y)$ and my PDE is a function of x and y. How I should test this then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's $\delta'(x-a)$. This is the distribution such that
$$\int \delta'(x-a) \, \varphi(x) \, dx = - \int \delta(x-a) \ \varphi'(x) \, dx = - \varphi'(a)$$
for every test function $\varphi.$

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. Let's say, I have a function of $\delta (x-y) H(y)$ and want its derivative to both x and y. How I can apply this?

Comment: Are you asking about partial derivatives of $u(x,y) := \delta(x-y)H(y)$? What derivatives do you want?

Comment: Yes, exactly, I want $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$